# Why is this not a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: matlab

I'm very confused by the following code:

```
>> x = [0.4+randn(100,1).*0.15; 1+ randn(200,1).*0.25];

>> size(x)

ans = 
    300    1
```

I thought semicolons were used to indicate a separate row in the matrix.  Shouldn't this raise an error given that the two vectors are not of the same length?

What am I missing?

Comment: Use a comma instead of the semicolon.

Comment: if you use a comma it will raise an error due to inconsistent dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you create 2 arrays and concatenate those:

randn(100,1) creates a 100 row, 1 column array
randn(200,1) creates a 200 row, 1 column array

The semicolon in your expression says: 'Put these underneath each other'
If you remove the semicolon (;) it will be a matrix (and probably give an error). As you then put 2 column vectors next to each other.

Comment: Oh I see it!  We're working in the vertical dimension here, so saying "put this vertical column on the row beneath this other vertical column" is akin to calling `cat`.  Thanks!  This was a major brain fart =/